# Why would passengers be required to close window shades when passing Ukraine

Tags: passenger, cabin

Last week, my friend flew from Europe to Japan, passing Ukraine to the south along the southern coast of Black Sea. When nearing the Black Sea area, the passengers were required to draw the shades on all cabin windows. The daytime was drawing to and end at this point.

Do you know of any reason relating to the war in Ukraine that would cause an airline to issue such a demand or is this rather just the standard procedure of darkening the cabin for the night during an eastbound flight?

The main reason we started to wonder about this is that dinner would still be served after issuing the command so it was not like majority of the passengers would be looking to sleep just yet. Personally I am skeptical that the passengers would be able to see explosions, missile trails or other alarming phenomena from the other side of the sea.

Comment: it's normal for long distance flights to have passengers to close the shades in the cruise portion of the flight to facilitate sleep. closing them before serving dinner is not unheard of for me, as you say "The daytime was drawing to and end at this point"